# OpenXML - how to save spreadsheetdocument to stream?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am getting an .xlsx document from a stream (using `SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, false)` then storing it into a Spreadsheetdocument field so that I can maintain the same object later.

I have a save method where I should ideally be able to save the SpreadsheetDocument to a stream. There is `document..WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(stream);` but that just gives me an empty file, and when I save only the first sheet (using `document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.Save(stream);` the file is a mess and does not contain the relevant information. How do I save a spreadsheetdocument to a stream?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little old but I stumbled across the question when having the same issue so thought I'd update it with the solution I found.

My issue turned out to be that I need to set the stream position back to zero.

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

From my experimentation, the position of the stream once the spreadsheet has been saved is the end of the stream. When I outputted my stream to a web browser, it starts the stream from the current position and runs to the end rather than starting from the start. I would assume this is consistent with other API's in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`SpreadsheetDocument.Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close%28v=office.14%29.aspx) *Saves and closes the OpenXml package plus all underlying part streams.*

**Update:**
Have you tried saving the underlying stream itself?

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, stream.ToArray());
```

Comment: Tried closing it after save, closing it instead of saving it, and it still gives me the same result. It has so be something within the OpenXML library itself. Unless it just cannot save a spreadsheetdocument that was opened from an outside source and not created from scratch.

Comment: There _shouldn't_ be a problem with spreadsheets from external sources, as that is one of the simple use cases for the library. I've not used the OpenXML library too much, as I much prefer the [ClosedXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library, which is built on top of OpenXml. It has a much nicer api, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, ClosedXml is much better, but I am not in a position to suggest changing libraries. Either way, the end result is not something that can be opened in Excel anyways, so I will probably end up ditching this and just doing a simple copying of the file. What it's generating is a .xlsx file containing XML that is mostly useless.